# DBSCAN : Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dbscan

I have two columns in a dataframe:

```
id    counts
1     0
2     1.90
3     3.99
4     0
5     1.90
........
........
560   3.99
```

trying to run this code where X is the dataframe

```
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=200).fit(X)
```

But there is an error

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for      dtype('float64')
```

I am not sure what is the error here. Because if I run this code with fewer data (20-30) instead of 560 rows it works. I do not know how to handle this error for a large dataset

Comment: what do you get for `X.isna().sum()`?

Comment: I get  :     
id               0
counts    576415
dtype: int64

Comment: That means your data contain 576415 `na` values, and cannot be used with the `fit` function. You need to decide what to do with those `na`'s, either drop them or fill them with something else.

Comment: Okay Thanks!   I will try doing that

Comment: Just a quick question. I know it sounds silly! So does DBscan only work with int or float ? Not with String value ? because I can not drop the nan values and cant assign 0 as  i already have 0 in my counts data

Comment: I have no idea, was just reading the error log. Looks like it works on `float64`.

Comment: Okay thanks anyhow :)

Comment: DBSCAN does not require the data to be numeric. But the default distance function, Euclidean, does.

Comment: Oh okay Thank you